# Restructuring existing JSON based on category in react native

Tags: android, ios, json, reactjs, react-native

I have a JSON response that I get from the server like below

```
    {
  "questionList": [{
      "qno": "1",
      "state_name": "State1",
      "category_name": "Category1",
      "question_type": "type1",
      "question": "This is question 11",
      "options": ["No", "yes "]
    },
    {
      "qno": "2",
      "state_name": "State1",
      "category_name": "Category1",
      "question_type": "type1",
      "question": "This is question12",
      "options": ["No", "yes "]
    },
    {
      "qno": "3",
      "state_name": "State1",
      "category_name": "Category2",
      "question_type": "type2",
      "question": "This is question 21",
      "options": ["No ", "yes "]
    },
    {
      "qno": "4",
      "state_name": "State1",
      "category_name": "Category3",
      "question_type": "type1",
      "question": "This is question 31",
      "options": ["No ", "yes "]
    },
    {
      "qno": "5",
      "state_name": "State1",
      "category_name": "Category3",
      "question_type": "type1",
      "question": "This is question 32",
      "options": ["No ", "yes "]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to restructure it based on category so that questions with multiple same categories will fall under a single category and also few of my own variables. Below is a sample output of how it should look like.

```
    [
  {
    "state": "State1",
    "category": "Category1",
    "questions": [
      {
        "questionID": "1",
        "question": "This is question 11",
        "options": ["No ", "yes "],
        "status": 0,
        "files": [],
        "questionType": "type1"
      },
     {
        "questionID": "2",
        "question": "This is question12",
        "options": ["No ", "yes "],
        "status": 0,
        "files": [],
        "questionType": "type1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "state": "State1",
    "category": "Category2",
    "questions": [
      {
        "questionID": "3",
        "question": "This is question 21",
        "options": ["No ", "yes "],
        "status": 0,
        "files": [],
        "questionType": "type2"
      }

    ]
  },
{
    "state": "State1",
    "category": "Category3",
    "questions": [
      {
        "questionID": "4",
        "question": "This is question 31",
        "options": ["No ", "yes "],
        "status": 0,
        "files": [],
        "questionType": "type1"
      },
     {
        "questionID": "5",
        "question": "This is question 32",
        "options": ["No ", "yes "],
        "status": 0,
        "files": [],
        "questionType": "type1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm not really an expert in JSON operations. Could anyone tell me shat should be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Can a category have multiple states?

Comment: No, only one state allowed for a particular category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if we take the questionList array from the json that you provided we can do the following.

1. Loop over each question in the questionList array.
2. Convert the question to the new format.
3. Check to see if we have come across the category before.

   - If we have not, we are going to create the category, add the new question to it, and add the category to our results array.
   - If we have found the category before then we are going to find it in the results array and add the new question to it.

Here is the code

```
let data = [{qno: "1", state_name: "State1", ... }, ... ] // notice that this is the questionList array and not an object
let categories = [];     // to track the categories that you have found
let result = [];        // where your results will be stored

data.forEach(question => {

  // create the question
  let newQuestion = {};
  newQuestion.questionID = question.qno;
  newQuestion.question = question.question;
  newQuestion.options = question.options;
  newQuestion.status = 0;
  newQuestion.files = [];
  newQuestion.questionType = question.question_type;

  // check to see if we have the category, if not create it
  if (categories.indexOf(question.category_name) === -1) {
    // create a new category
    let newCategory = {};
    newCategory.state = question.state_name;
    newCategory.category = question.category_name;
    newCategory.questions = [];

    newCategory.questions.push(newQuestion);  // add the question to the category we just created
    result.push(newCategory);                 // add the category to the result
    categories.push(question.category_name);  // track the category so we know not to create a new one
  } else {
    // search for the category
    let foundCategory = result.filter(group => group.category === question.category_name);
    // if we have found a category add the new question to it
    if (foundCategory.length) {
      foundCategory[0].questions.push(newQuestion);
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked well :). Just to let you know there's a spelling error for variable name result in your code, you can edit if you want to ;)